# Using std::map stored in a std::any and then accessed via std::any_cast

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to understand the results from the following code:

```
template<typename KeyTypeT, typename ValueTypeT>
class MapWrapper {
    std::any _container;

    MapWrapper() {
        _container = std::map<KeyTypeT, ValueTypeT>();
    }

    void insert(KeyTypeT key, ValueTypeT value) {
       auto originalMap = std::any_cast<std::map<KeyTypeT, ValueTypeT>>(_container);
       std::cout << "count is " << originalMap.size() << std::endl;

       auto afterInsertion = std::any_cast<std::map<KeyTypeT, ValueTypeT>>(_container);
       afterInsertion.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
       std::cout << "count is " << afterInsertion.size() << std::endl;

       auto originalMapAfterInsertion = std::any_cast<std::map<KeyTypeT, ValueTypeT>>(_container);
       std::cout << "count is " << originalMapAfterInsertion.size() << std::endl;


       _container = afterInsertion;
       auto originalMapAfterAssignement = std::any_cast<std::map<KeyTypeT, ValueTypeT>>(_container);
       std::cout << "count is " << originalMapAfterAssignement.size() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The results are as follows:

```
Test Results:
count is 0
count is 1
count is 0 // why is this not 1?
count is 1
```

My question is why does `_container` not contain the newly inserted key until after I do an assignment?

Is `std::any_cast` returning a copy to the `std::map<KeyTypeT, ValueTypeT>`? I would have expected it to return the original map. Is there a way to modify the original map stored in the `std::any`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overload of [`any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) that you are using (#2) gives you a *copy* of the value held by the `any`, not a reference to it. So the `map` that you're inserting into is a different `map` than the one the `any` is holding.

If you want to directly modify what the `any` is holding, you need to use one of the overloads that take the `any` by pointer (i.e. #5):

```
std::any a = 1;
int* p = std::any_cast<int>(&a); // <== like this
assert(p);
*p = 42;
assert(std::any_cast<int>(a) == 42);
```

Or you can explicitly provide a reference type into `any_cast`:

```
std::any a = 1;
std::any_cast<int&>(a) = 42; // <== int&, not int
assert(std::any_cast<int>(a) == 42);
```

---

Also note that even if `any_cast` itself wasn't giving you a copy, you're making one yourself by writing:

```
auto originalMap = ...;
```

instead of taking a reference to the result. So you probably wanted:

```
auto& map = std::any_cast<std::map<...>&>(_container);
```

Comment: Is either considered better practice? Or is it preference?

Comment: @markf78 One throws if you provide the wrong type, the other returns a null pointer. So really that should probably drive the decision - how do you want to handle your error.

Answer (score 0):

Your any_cast is returning a copy - try return a pointer to the contained object or wrap in std::reference_wrapper